# how to prevent image wrap in responsive mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

how to prevent image wrap in responsive mode. A simple code like below is break to new line in responsive mode.

```
<img src="image1.jpg" style="float:left;" />
<img src="image2.jpg" style="float:left;" />
<img src="image3.jpg" style="float:left;" />
<img src="image4.jpg" style="float:left;" />
<img src="image5.jpg" style="float:left;" />
```

please help

**Edit:** 
see this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/AhIwiCA/1/edit

Comment: No I only have this images in a bootstrap style div with col-xs-12 class

Comment: @babak haj azim zanjani could you provide a jsFiddle

Comment: We need your code (with bootstrap div) to be able to help you !

Comment: see this: http://jsbin.com/AhIwiCA/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent the images from wrapping, then add a `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent element and remove the `style="float:left;` from the images.

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/gqxxC/

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a class called inline I believe which may bring the images in line with each other, failing that you may need to trawl through the css to find the relevant css class to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: so just to confirm? you want it the images stacked on top of each other at all times or only in a certain screen size?

Comment: I want images stacked on top at all time.